# How to plot proportions with geom_bar while scaling by total count for each factor

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

Here's a short example

```r
library(ggplot2) 
specie <- c(rep("sorgho" , 5) , rep("poacee" , 5) , rep("banana" , 5) , rep("triticum" , 5) )
  condition <- rep(c("normal" , "stress" , "Nitrogen","Nitrogen","Nitrogen") , 4)
  data <- data.frame(specie,condition)
  ggplot(data) +  aes(x = factor(specie), fill=condition) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill")
```

[[image]]
I would like to correct for the over-abundance of "Nitrogen" and plot only it's relative contribution.
Thanks